# JQuery toggle function only works on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a problem using the JQuery toggle function.  As far as I understand, performing the toggle function should hide a div if it is currently shown and show the div if it is currently hidden.  At the moment my toggle function isn't working because it only works once when I click the button to cause the event, after clicking again it does nothing so basically it just permanently hides the div which is not ideal.

The div is quite packed with a whole bunch of things including an image and the JQuery Accordion as well, but the hide works perfectly how I'd want it to.

I should also mention that I'm doing this in an asp.net project in case that might have anything to do with it.

Below is the html code the div that needs to be hidden and the button that causes the toggle function to run:

```
<div id="sidebar-left">
  <!--All info in here-->
</div>

<asp:LinkButton ID="ShowHideButton" runat="server" CssClass="fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-state-default ui-corner-all showHide"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"></span>Hide Menu</asp:LinkButton>
```

Below is the javascript code of the toggle use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ShowHideButton').click(function () {
     $('#sidebar-left').toggle('slide');
  })
});
```

I still plan to add other functionality in like changing the value on the button to "Show Menu" after the toggle function is called and back to hide again but that will happen after I solve the issue where the menu stays hidden.

For the record, I've tested this using hide() and show() method in one click of the button and it also only worked once.

Appreciate any help that comes my way...

Comment: An anchor generally redirects to another page, it's what they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is postback So do the following:

ASPX code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ShowHideButton" runat="server" CssClass="fg-button fg-button-icon-left ui-state-default ui-corner-all showHide"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"></span>Hide Menu</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowHideButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
    }
}
```

What renders as HTML is:

```
<a onclick="return false;" id="ShowHideButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ShowHideButton','')"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"></span>Hide Menu</a>
```

In this case, what happens is the onclick functionality becomes your validator. If it is false, the "href" link is not executed; however, if it is true the href will get executed. This eliminates your post back.

Answer (score 1):

The `runat="server"` will make the button act like a server control. I guess it also adjusts the click event.

Answer (score 0):

try below one, it works for me,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="sidebar-left">
    <p>Volley Ball</p>
    <p>Foot Ball</p>
    <p>Base Ball</p>
    <p>Golf</p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="ShowHideButton" />

</body>
<style>
.hidden{display:none;}
</style>
<script>



$('#ShowHideButton').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar-left p').toggle();
});


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

why are you calling `.toggle('slide')`? call `.toggle()` to show/hide or `.slideToggle()` to slide toggle

Comment: slide just makes it look cool when you toggle, I've tried it without slide and have the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ShowHideButton').click(function () {
     $('#sidebar-left').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Thanks